# VRAM management with opengl and OOP design

Tags: c++, oop, opengl, 3d

I have a SceneNode class which contains pointer to mesh and material. Now I want to create a class for rendering my scenegraph (SceneNodes), so I named the class "GLrenderer" and add a method to render SceneNodes.

My mesh class does not contain VAO nor anything related to opengl, it only contains a vector of vertices, normals etc ...
So for the rendering method I was thinking about simply creating different buffer objects (VBOs), for vertices, normals etc., then load them by getting scenenodes mesh and meshes data, activate the shader which is in the scenenodes material, render, deactivate shader, and finally destroy buffer objects.

The problem is if I do this I would have to create and destroy buffer objects every frame, I was thinking that everytime I load data to mesh, I create the buffer objects and use a VAO, and I simply bind / unbind the VAO which would be created only once.

- But where should the VAO be ? In the mesh class ? With a method like
  "updateBufferData();" that I'd call every time I modify mesh data ?
- When we create and load buffers, does it took VRAM even if the buffers are not binded ? Because if I would create buffers for every mesh of my application, even those who are not rendered, it would took to much VRAM, would it ?
- How would you manage this stuff (rendering, buffers objects..) if you were creating a tiny and simple 3d/opengl engine ?

Comment: I get the impression from reading your question that you are not entirely sure what a VAO represents. VAOs actually do not store anything in memory, they only keep track of vertex pointer state and the currently bound element buffer. Really if you are modifying mesh data you are going to be touching ***buffer objects*** and the VAO probably will not have to change at all unless you change the underlying structure of the data stored (e.g. number of components, stride, data type). That is because VAOs store pointers to VBO memory, not the actual VBOs themselves.

Comment: So when we create a buffer object ( when a VAO is bind ), bind it, change data, and unbind it, this buffer object ( which the VAO will point on ) will took memory even if both the VAO (pointer) and VBO are not bind ? And I am able to change the buffer object without binding again the VAO ? (Sorry I'am a beginner in opengl) I'll edit the question

Comment: Yes, the only time binding a VBO matters is immediately before you call `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`. It tells that command which buffer the pointer is related to. But after that function returns, you can bind anything you want to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and it will not make a difference.

Comment: I got the impression you want to load the data into VBO per frame that is not a good idea because you loose most of the VBO speed boost. load only on change... static objects (not changing color,shape,...) should stay in VBO ...